# What is that and how to remove this styling in Chrome?

Tags: html, css

Today, when testing my website in Chrome i noticed a strange thing. Sorry if topic appeared before somewhere, but I even dont know how to name it and search.

In the picture below, on the left side you have styling for `:link`, on the right side you have style for `:hover`, and in the middle it changes style after being clicked, **but not proceeded** to the `href`. For example, it happens when I click and drag the button. In Firefox I have not this.

What is that and how to remove it?

[image: EXAMPLE]

Comment: That's `:active`

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol ok, thanks, I will remove topic shortly...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the `:active` attribute that is appearing on your links. The `:active` attribute is a CSS pseudo-class and it highlights elements that are active or can be active upon a certain action. This can be shown by either clicking on the link or tapping if on a mobile device.

To remove this, you will have to navigate to your CSS, find the styling for that menu and look for (in most cases) `a :active{}` and delete that. Since we don't have the code you are using, it is hard to pinpoint what exactly you should remove but that will at least give you a good starting point.